# Split a string into a vector of words

Tags: c++, string, stream

I have a `string` like `"ABC DEF "` with whitespace at the end. I would like to convert it into a `vector` of strings like `{"ABC" "DEF"}`, so I used a `stringstream`:

```
string s = "ABC DEF ";
stringstream ss(s);
string tmpstr;
vector<string> vpos;
while (ss.good())
{
    ss >> tmpstr;
    vpos.push_back(tmpstr);
}
```

However, the result `vpos` is `{"ABC" "DEF" "DEF"}`. Why the last word will be duplicated in the vector? And what is the correct code if using `stringstream` is required?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Not really, no.

Comment: Basic logic: `ss.good()` can't tell the future!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - quite right. Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 4):

`ss.good()` only tells you whether things have been good so far.  It doesn't tell you that the next thing you read will be good.

Use

```
while (ss >> tmpstr) vpos.push_back(tmpstr);
```

Now you are reading `tmpstr` first and then checking the state of the stream.  It is equivalent to this:

```
for (;;) {
    istream &result = ss >> tmpstr;
    if (!result) break;
    vpos.push_back(tmpstr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I found the return value is of type `istream`, so I wrote `while (istream obj = ss >> tmpstr) `, but it seems wrong. So what's the syntax behind `ss >> tmpstr`?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I learned a lot.